# Where is .htaccess? and should I do it server wide or per cpanel account?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I want to do this?

http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/

```
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# Or, compress certain file types by extension:
<files *.html>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>
```

is there an .htaccess server wide? and where?

Should I do this server wide or per account? we have 4 accounts in my server, 3 magento accounts and one wordpress.

What are the benefits of doing it in each account or server wide?

Comment: Please read the documentation first http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html and let us know if you have any problems once you have a minimal understanding of .htaccess files.

Comment: I already did, the question still remains the same, please re open it.

Comment: If you had read the documentation your question would reflect *some* understanding of what a .htaccess file does. Your question does not demonstrate a minimal understanding for a professional system administrator. If the question does not accurately reflect your understanding please edit the Question and it will automatically get flagged for review.

Comment: who said I was a professional system admin? I am a developer that needs to setup something by myself, if I cant get help because of this, that is a shame on a site like this.

Comment: @L.V.SharepointArchitect - If you read the help section, you'll see that SF is explicitly for systems and network professionals, or those acting in such a role. We don't have a hard requirement that people have a sysadmin job title, but we do expect *everyone* who asks questions here to do so in a professional manner. That means - doing research on your own, trying things, reporting on what didn't work, etc. Read [How do I ask a good question](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask). Come back after reading that, and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it at whatever level you want it to apply, be that individual sites or site wide.

The better way, however, is to put it in Apache's configuration files, not a .htaccess file.

Comment: @L.V.SharepointArchitect Usually in /etc/apache.

Comment: nop there :( thxvm